# Failed to find required executable brew in paths - Ansible

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ansible

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my Windows 10 and I am trying to run a playbook:

```
---
  - name: "My first play"
    hosts: localhost

    tasks:

      - name: "test reachability"
        ping:

      - name: "install stress"
        homebrew:
          name: stress
          state: present
```

But I get this error on the second task:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable brew in paths: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Replace "homebrew" with "apt". If you get a password error, try running the command with "sudo"

Answer (score 0):

you can replace homebrew with either apt or package.
Although package is advisable as it will allow ansible to automatically detect package manager to be used based on your host.
once done you can run you ansible script as

```
sudo ansible-playbook first.yaml
```

it should work fine
using homebrew threw an error as it was not pre installed you can follow below doc for it
https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux